# My JFrame window won't appear

Tags: java, swing

My `JFrame` window won't appear, though, by the tutorial I've been watching, I've been doing everything spot on, yet nothing happens.  It doesn't even give me an error, which makes it so much worse.  This is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Window {

    public class Window {

    public void newWindow() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("I am a star!  A beautiful shining star!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);


        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

(This is a second class, the main one properly links to this one)

Comment: Please show the other class, the one that "properly links to this one". Please show how your call the code from this class. I'm guessing that your main method is in that other class, and that your error is in that class as well.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: The code examples looks...strange...can you verify that's exactly what you have...

Comment: Why is `Window` nested in `Window`?

Comment: Oh, the filename was Window.java, and I made the method name Window

Answer (score 1):

JFrame uses a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) named BorderLayout by default. To see components added to the frame, you should refer to its [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html). However, the easiest choice here is to use [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html). You also should use JFrame's [pack()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()) method, which, according to Oracle:

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents. The resulting width and height of the window are automatically enlarged if either of dimensions is less than the minimum size as specified by the previous call to the setMinimumSize method.

Thus, this should work for you:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Window {

    public void newWindow() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // specify the layout manager
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("I am a star!  A beautiful shining star!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        frame.pack(); // handles sizing of the window
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Notice that I removed the duplicate `public class Window` declaration, which might have been the reason you didn't see a frame at all. If it's still not working for you, I think you aren't calling the `newWindow()` method. If you want the window to show by simply calling `new Window();`, then you should change `public void newWindow()` to `public Window()`.

Comment: `JFrame` by default, uses a `BorderLayout`, having said that, even without `pack`, the OP should still the frame border when the frame is made visible, but they state they see nothing...

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that when I read over my code in Eclipse, I noticed that I actually had newWindow as the method, but just didn't put it here.  I guess I forgot.

Comment: Something else, I didn't even know that the .setLayout was a thing.  I think that's where I went wrong.

Comment: Get rid of the void, eh?  I'll try that.

Comment: This is the main method:

Comment: public class SimpleGui {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
  Window window1 = new Window();
  
  window1.newWindow();
   
  }
}

Comment: To be honest, I don't think I'll ever be able to get JFrame to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Window {
public void newWindow() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("I am a star!  A beautiful shining star!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
  }
}
```

Comment: This code cannot work. You're calling the undefined method `pack` and please remove the second class declaration.

Comment: I don't like manipulating code from someone else, expect fixing the indentation. So I had no other "choice". And I always revert the downvote, if the problems are fixed :).

Comment: @Tom you are right :) , I was in hurry so I did not noticed it sorry

Comment: hurried answered are no benefit to anyone

Answer (score -2):

From what I see, your not setting the size of the JFrame. Try,

```
frame.setSize(500, 500);
```

Comment: I like how I went to the Colorado School of Mines' website, copied and pasted the code that they had there, and still, nothing appeared.